# Dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 with windows 8

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

I'm attempting to dual boot Win8 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I already had Win8 installed and have Ubuntu installed, and when booting I am given the option to boot either Win8 or Ubuntu, but when I click Ubuntu it gives me an error "\NST\AutoNeoGrub0.mbr". I then mounted Boot Repair to a USB flash drive and tried to run it, but it had to abort and gave an "EFI detected" error. The link that Boot Repair gave is here http://paste.ubuntu.com/7302051/.

Answer (score 0):

Boot Repair *should* have no problems with your setup, although you should be careful to boot your emergency disc in EFI mode, since Windows is installed in that way. Your Boot Repair output indicates that GRUB is installed in BIOS mode, and there's no evidence of an EFI-mode installation of GRUB, so my suspicion is that this is the root of your problem. I therefore recommend that you first attempt to get your emergency system booted in EFI mode by fiddling with your boot-time options. Check for a directory called `/sys/firmware/efi`; if it's present, you've booted Linux in EFI mode, and if it's not, you probably haven't.

If you have problems with that, you could try my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) instead. Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version from [its downloads page,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) prepare a medium with it, and boot to it. If the rEFInd menu appears and enables you to boot either Ubuntu or Windows, boot to Ubuntu and install the Debian-package version.